# How to convert from varchar to float and ignore non-numeric characters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to convert a column from varchar(500) to float in my sql.
My code currently looks like this:

```
select distinct(customer_id), cast(val_amt as float) from(
select prsn_real_gid, vital_nam, vital_performed_date,
case when val_amt ~'^[0-9]+' then val_amt else null end as val_amt from my_table);
```

but I get the following error message

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Invalid digit, Value 'X', Pos 2, Type: Double 
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid digit, Value 'X', Pos 2, Type: Double 
  code:      1207
  context:   1.XYXY04
  query:     4147
  location:  :0
  process:   query0_118_4147 [pid=0]
  -----------------------------------------------;
1 statement failed.
```

My data for example looks like this:

```
customer_id  |  val_amt
111  | 23.45
112  | 21
113  | x
114  | /
115  |
```

It has alpha characters, symbols, and nulls. I just want the numbers including the decimals.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you would use `try_cast()`:

```
select distinct customer_id, try_cast(val_amt as float)
from my_table;
where try_cast(val_amt as float) is not null;
```

Comment: I got the error "syntax error at or near as" in the first try_cast

Comment: @brightman1309 . . . `try_cast()` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is supported in every supported version of SQL Server.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without try_cast? I copied and pasted your code directly but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: Are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server, @brightman1309 ? (2008 or prior)

Comment: Correction: this is a my sql server. I got confused, sorry.

Comment: If you are using MySQL, @brightman1309 update you question's tags (and invalidate all the answers that you've now received... ).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Cast gives me problems. Even Try_Cast(). This may be good for what you need. **EDIT**: You changed from SQLServer to MySQL. Adjusted for MySQL

```
select distinct customer_id, convert(`val_amt`, float(2,2))
from my_table
where convert(`val_amt`,float(2,2)) is not null;
```

Comment: I got a syntax error at the comma in the try_convert

Comment: I didn't see you changed your DBMS to MySQL. You need to update your Question. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this using **[isnumeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)**

```
select customer_id, case when isnumeric([val_amt])=0 
enter code herethen 0 else cast([val_amt] as float) end from my_table
```

Comment: I got the following error: Invalid operation: function isnumeric(character varying) does not exist;